# asp.net UserControl click event to run a function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-interface

i have a asp.net webform app with `employees.aspx` and a user control `usercontrol1.ascx`  as follows

**employees.aspx**

i have placed `usercontrol1.ascx` inside my `employees.aspx` and i need to run a function `get_employees()` which is inside `employees.aspx`

**usercontrol1.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="usercontrol2.ascx.vb" Inherits="wogapp.usercontrol1" %>
<asp:Button ID="btnEmpDetails" runat="server" Text="Employee Details"  class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: You need to look at using a delegate. Some more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/

Comment: i have followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/how-to-invoke-a-delegate-method) and almost made it to run a function just to show a message , but any other function show error saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`